# how to tackle when text data as a feature and the label to be predicted is a number ?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, text-analysis

I have the following material description as feature and some code as the label

```
AIRTEL BILLS 22aug TO 23 AUG    2012       83111500
 AIRTEL MOBILE BILLS 23nov O 22 dec 12      83111500
 aluminum fabrication work                  72121100
 aluminum fabrication work                  72121100
 civil & plumbing work @ BMT                72153600
 ELECTRICAL WK 09ELR LAB @ MHB              72151500
 Airtel Bill
 AIRTEL LAND LINE BILL MHB APRIL 2012
 airtel mobile bill -FEB-2013
```

Any suggestions on which Machine learning or neural network model that can help me predict that since the keywords 'Airtel','bill' appears, so the code will be 
83111500

Comment: I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve. Surely you are not expecting a neural network to magically figure out which number you want to extract from the above text snippet?

Comment: In real world, those material description are categorized into 4 sub categories. Segment, class, family, and another one....so each will have 2 digit code....at the end, all are concatenated​ together to get 8 digit code.... But in the dataset given, only for some of the fields, segment, class, family are given...so the only trusted field is Material Description now

Comment: Can i train the network by having the frequency of words ? How to do it ?